# how to make a function that disable the other buttons

Tags: java, android, button, methods

I am creating a trivia game that get the user answer from the choice of answer button. i would like to make a function that disable the other buttons (answer choices) when the user had tap on a button as answer. Currently, when user pressed multiple buttons continuously the answer(tapped answer) would be use as the answer for the next questions depending on how many taps. I had tried to put a boolean flag to disable other buttons but it will disable to go to the next question.

Here are my codes for the buttons.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.choice1_Button) :
            if (choice1.getText().equals(answer)) {
                correct = 1;
                sound(correct);
                score += 10;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Brilliant! The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }else {
                correct = 0;
                sound(correct);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nice try. The correct answer is "+answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (score > 0) {
                    score = score - 3;
                }
                if (score < 0){
                    score = 0;
                }
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }
            break;
        case (R.id.choice2_Button) :
            if (choice2.getText().equals(answer)) {
                correct = 1;
                sound(correct);
                score += 10;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Brilliant! The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }else {
                correct = 0;
                sound(correct);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nice try. The correct answer is "+answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (score > 0) {
                    score = score - 3;
                }
                if (score < 0){
                    score = 0;
                }
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }
            break;
        case (R.id.choice3_Button) :
            if (choice3.getText().equals(answer)) {
                correct = 1;
                sound(correct);
                score += 10;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Brilliant! The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }else {
                correct = 0;
                sound(correct);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nice try. The correct answer is "+answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (score > 0) {
                    score = score - 3;
                }
                if (score < 0){
                    score = 0;
                }
                scoreboard(score);
                getNextQuestion(counter);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

here is my getNextQuestion method

```
private void getNextQuestion(final int i) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (counter < 6) {
                setQuestion();
            }else {
                // if over 5 do this
                Intent intent = new Intent(Level6.this, NextLevel.class);
                Bundle a = new Bundle();
                a.putInt("score", score);
                a.putInt("level", 6);
                intent.putExtras(a);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    },500);
}
```

Here is my setQuestion() method

```
private void setQuestion() {
    emotion_View.setImageResource(questionsLib.getQuestions(counter));
    choice1.setText(questionsLib.getOptions1(counter));
    choice2.setText(questionsLib.getOptions2(counter));
    choice3.setText(questionsLib.getOptions3(counter));
    answer = questionsLib.getCorrectAnswer(counter);
    counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make method that disable group of buttons, something like this:

```
private void setQuestion(Boolean enable) {
    choice1.setEnabled(enable);
    choice2.setEnabled(enable);
    choice3.setEnabled(enable);
}
```

1. Then before `getNextQuestion` execute this method to set buttons disable (`setQuestion(false)`)
2. After stetting next question enable buttons by method (`setQuestion(true)`)  in your handler.

or you can set it all in your `getNextQuestion` method:

```
private void getNextQuestion(final int i) {
    setQuestion(false); //disable buttons
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (counter < 6) {
                setQuestion();
            }else {
                // if over 5 do this
                Intent intent = new Intent(Level6.this, NextLevel.class);
                Bundle a = new Bundle();
                a.putInt("score", score);
                a.putInt("level", 6);
                intent.putExtras(a);
                startActivity(intent);
                setQuestion(true); //enable buttons
                finish();
            }
        }
    },500);
}
```